# Passing an array of Strings from inside a Static Function in a different class to another class

Tags: java, arrays, string, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to get the arrays 't','p' and 's' from the class 'BuildOrder' to another class. Here is the code for reference:

I tried to create methods to return them and retrieve them in another class but I am out of ideas how to do it. I am trying to add Decorator pattern to a base code of Composite pattern
Component here is an interface for the Composite pattern

```
package composite;

public class BuildOrder {

public static Component getOrder()
{
    Composite order = new Composite( "Order" ) ;
    order.addChild(new Leaf("Crispy Onion Strings", 5.50 ));
    order.addChild(new Leaf("The Purist", 8.00 ));
    //Composite customBurger = new Composite( "Build Your Own Burger" ) ;


    String[] t={"Bermuda Red Onion","Black Olives","Carrot           Strings","Coleslaw"};

    String[] p={"Applewood Smoked Bacon"};

    String[] s={"Apricot Sauce"};

    /*customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Beef, 1/3 lb on a Bun",9.50 )); // base price for 1/3 lb
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Danish Blue Cheese", 0.00 )); // 1 cheese free, extra cheese +1.00
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Horseradish Cheddar", 1.00 )); // extra cheese +1.00
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Bermuda Red Onion", 0.00 )); // 4 toppings free, extra +.75
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Black Olives", 0.00 )); // 4 toppings free, extra +.75
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Carrot Strings", 0.00 )); // 4 toppings free, extra +.75
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Coleslaw", 0.00 )); // 4 toppings free, extra +.75
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Applewood Smoked Bacon", 1.50 )); // premium topping +1.50
    customBurger.addChild(new Leaf("Apricot Sauce", 0.00  )); // 1 sauce free, extra +.75
    order.addChild( customBurger );*/
    return order ;

}
    public String[] gettoppings()
    { return t;
    }
     public String[] getpremium()
    { return p;
    }
    public String[] getSauces()
    { return s;
    }
}

//following is the class where I want to use the above strings 
public class Sauce implements LeafDecorator
{
public String Sauce()
{   BuildOrder bo=new BuildOrder();
    String[] order=bo.getSauces(String[] s);

}
}
```

Comment: what the use of public String gettoppings(String t)
    { return t;
    } ? it returns the input directly?

Comment: @HendrikT this is my try to make a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be more than one mismatch in this example.

You define the class variables...

```
String[] t;
String[] p;
String[] s;
```

but then you define them again within your `getOrder()` method -- covering the class-level variables within the scope of that method.

NOTE:  The way you have them, these variables are package-private (default access specifier).  I would probably go with `private`.

The methods `gettoppings`, `getpremium`, and `getSauces` (inside the `BuildOrder` class) are pointless -- they always return exactly what they are passed.

The class `Sauce` doesn't look like it will compile.  This should compile (depending on `LeafDecorator`)...

```
public class Sauce implements LeafDecorator {

    public String Sauce() {
        BuildOrder bo = new BuildOrder();
        String order = bo.getSauces("some string -- what's this for?");
    }

}
```

The `order` String will be equal to "some string -- what's this for?".

Comment: I agree with the first thing you pointed out. I shouldn't have declared them again in the getOrder() function. I fixed it and declared them only inside getOrder() but when I try to change he access specifier to private right there, I get an error saying illegal start of expression.

Comment: In the class Sauce, the line of code saying 
 String[] order = bo.getSauces("some string -- what's this for?");

I am trying to set the array 'order' to the array 's' from getOrder(). 

This is my ultimate goal.. thats the reason I asked this question.
I also noticed that I was confusing the arrays 't' 'p' and 's' being a String..
And so I changed it ..in the comments here

Comment: If you declare `t`, `p`, and `s` inside of `getOrder()` they will only exist in there, and only for the lifetime of the method invocation.  (Also public/private/protected cannot be applied to variables defined inside methods... only class-level variables.)  If those things need to live longer than the method call -- and need to be accessible outside the method call -- they need to be class members.

Comment: So, if I declare them outside the function getOrder() , but Initialize them inside this function; I cannot use those initialized values in another class..even by having those getter methods in the same class?

Comment: If you declare them outside the method, then set their values inside the method, those values will stay set after the method completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of those fiels, you may simply add getters to the class 'BuildOrder' which would return the different variables.

If you're using IntelliJ, simply press Alt+Insert, and then select 'Getter', highlight the 3 variables and press enter.

You may also simply set those variables public (add 'public ' in front of them), the access them by using 'bo.t', for example.

Comment: I tried changing the access specifier to public, but I get the error 'Illegal start of expression' and I am using BlueJ.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the arrays 't','p' and 's' from the class 'BuildOrder' to another class.

To get variables from another class (object) you make the element public and access it as `objectOfClass1.variable1` or you make them private and then create a getter and setter (if needed) so you can have

```
objectOfClass1.setVariable1("hello");
```

to set that variable and then to get you do

```
String var = objectOfClass1.getVariable1();
```

Note the signature, unlike your code a getter usually doesn't take a parameter and returns a value so

```
public String getVariable1(){ 
  return variable1; 
}
```

and

```
public void setVariable1(String s){
  this.variable1 = s;
}
```

---

**Edit** per your last change.

First things first you are declaring the variable String [] t; in your method. So, it will not be available at object level. And hence will not be accessible to your getter.

I don't want to give you exact code. I will however give you general idea.

```
public class myclass{

  String [] a;

  public void myInitializer(){
     a={"Hello","Bye"};
  }
  public String [] getA(){
    return a;
  }
}
```

That is how you are supposed to structure your code.

Second thing I noticed is your main method is supposed to return Component, however you are returning a Composite. This will not compile (unless its of same type).

```
  public static Component getOrder()
  {
    Composite order = new Composite( "Order" ) ;
    return order ;
  }
```

Also, your Sauce constructor is making a call to `bo.getSauces(String [] s)`

You don't have a method called getSauces that can take in an argument of String [] so, it will not compile again. You need to call it like this.

```
String[] order=bo.getSauces();
```

Comment: I do not need a setter method as I have initialized them already. And these were supposed to be arrays instead of strings, so made the changes above in the code. I have made some changes, to the best of my knowledge. Please review and leave me more comments.

Comment: modified my answer. I believed I have answered your original question on how to access value of variable.